# Windows Laptop as Secondary Monitor for Macbook Air (Preferably Wired)

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi, displayport

I have a Macbook Air and an HP Stream 13 and I am wondering if it is possible to use the HP Stream 13 as a secondary monitor (a more mobile solution to a secondary screen). I currently own a Mini DP to HDMI cable and I would prefer a wired connection since the HP Stream's wireless cards aren't the best.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). All the best with your question.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check this pair of software to extend your display

- Windows - https://www.sharemouse.com/
- Mac- https://www.screenrecycler.com/download.html

Answer (score 1):

This question already has an accepted answer on stackoveflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11067470/how-to-use-windows-laptop-as-external-monitor-for-macbook-pro

It requires downloading the following software:

- MaxiVista on PC
- [ScreenRecycler](https://www.screenrecycler.com/download.html) (for Mac)

It seems like Maxivista.com has migrated to https://www.sharemouse.com/ (Since MaxiVista has been discontinued and replaced by sharemouse)

Here's a website that still has a version of MaxiVista available: https://maxivista.jaleco.com/

Comment: This question is closed on stackoverflow, limiting the value of that question, which will slowly fall out of date.